# Where do I store important api keys in a blazor server app?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server app and I need to know here to store some important info for my app, in the appsettings.json, a .resx file? or somewhere else?

Answer (score 5):

Right click the project node in the Solution Explorer and choose `Manage User Secrets..`. The contents of the file that opens will be merged with the app settings so you can use them just like any other app setting, but they are stored securely on your machine, and are not put to e.g. source control. When you deploy the app, the server you deploy to will have its own secure storage strategy for production API keys etc (for example if you're publishing to Azure, Azure has options for safe storage of these kinds of info)

You can read more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows

Comment: I'm planning on deploying to azure, do you Azures options for storing this kind of info?

Comment: How secure do you want it to be? For the most part doing the config in the Azure portal UI config or environment varaibles might be enough for you, or you can check out the next article down in the MSDN contents list from the one I linked above, about using Azure KeyVault https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Add appsettings.secrets.json file to project for store secrets. After add appsettings.secrets.json file name to .gitignore